# Force excel to always open with Text encoding assistant

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I am looking for a way to force excel to always open .csv or txt files with the Text encoding assistant.

As I have opened a file and used the wrong settings (UTF8 - encoding issues with umlauts). Leading excel to automatically applying these settings if I try to reopen the file.
I also need to create documentation so other users know what they have to do.
So I need to be able to manually trigger the usage of this assistant when opening files in order to be able to create the documentation.

I already tried

1. deleteing excel cache
2. I created new files with other schematics and opened them with the
   Assistant
3. I used the text to column inside that file and changed delimiters to
   nothing
4. reboot pc

But no, every time I reopen the CSV file it applys the wrong settings.

Comment: Don't **Open** `.csv` files.  You should either **Import**, use `Power Query` to set up a connection; or change them to `.txt` files.

Comment: ok, thanks. Just changing `.csv` to `.txt` gives the desired result

Comment: I'll add that as an answer so you can close the question by accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't **Open** `.csv` files. You should either **Import**, use **Power Query** to set up a connection; or change them to **`.txt`**